# Discriminar datos segun dos atributos

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
let arreglo=[{'class':1,'var':1, 'valor':50},
            {'class':3,'var':2, 'valor':150},
            {'class':1,'var':2, 'valor':200},
            {'class':1,'var':1, 'valor':60},
            {'class':3,'var':2, 'valor':520},
            {'class':1,'var':2, 'valor':250}];
```

quiero discriminar ordenando segun el atributo 'class'

```
 [{'class':1,'var':1, 'valor':50},
        {'class':1,'var':2, 'valor':200},
        {'class':1,'var':1, 'valor':50},
        {'class':1,'var':2, 'valor':250}]

        [{'class':3,'var':2, 'valor':150},
        {'class':3,'var':2, 'valor':520}];
```

luego discriminar segun el atributo 'var' para obtener

```
[{'class':1,'var':1, 'valor':50},
         {'class':1,'var':1, 'valor':50},
         {'class':1,'var':2, 'valor':200},
        {'class':1,'var':2, 'valor':250}]
        [{'class':3,'var':2, 'valor':150},
        {'class':3,'var':2, 'valor':520}];
```

mi codigo es el siguiente pero lo que hago es discriminar y luego tendria que unir los arreglos, quiero una forma mas eficiente.

```js
let arreglo = [{'class': 1,'var': 1,'valor': 50},
  {'class': 3, 'var': 2,'valor': 150  },
  {'class': 1, 'var': 2,'valor': 200  },
  {'class': 1, 'var': 1,'valor': 60   },
  {'class': 3, 'var': 2,'valor': 520 },
  {'class': 1, 'var': 2,'valor': 250 }
];

function filtrarSegunVariable(arreglo, variable, condicion) {
  return arreglo.filter(function(x) {
    if (x[variable] === condicion) {
      return x;
    }
  })
}
let class1 = filtrarSegunVariable(arreglo, 'class', 1);
let class3 = filtrarSegunVariable(arreglo, 'class', 3);
console.log(filtrarSegunVariable(class1, 'var', 1));
console.log(filtrarSegunVariable(class1, 'var', 2));
console.log(filtrarSegunVariable(class3, 'var', 1));
console.log(filtrarSegunVariable(class3, 'var', 2));
```

> nota: los valores 1, 2, 3 deben ser cadenas

Comment: no entiendo la pregunta, lo que buscas en ordenar?

Comment: Prueba con esto [https://coderwall.com/p/5fu9xw/how-to-sort-multidimensional-array-using-javascript]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al método `sort` le puedes pasar una función de comparación. Entonces lo que podrías hacer es pasar una función que primero ordene comparando un valor (class) y, si son iguales, ordene comparando por un segundo valor (var) y, si son iguales, ordene comparando por un tercer valor (valor).

Algo como esto:

```
function(a,b) {
  // primer nivel: usando class
  if (a.class < b.class) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.class == b.class) {
    // si son iguales = segundo nivel: usando var
    if (a.var < b.var) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.var == b.var) {
      // si son iguales = tercer nivel: usando valor
      return a.valor >= b.valor;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
let arreglo = [
  {'class': 1, 'var': 1, 'valor': 50  },
  {'class': 3, 'var': 2, 'valor': 150 },
  {'class': 1, 'var': 2, 'valor': 200 },
  {'class': 1, 'var': 1, 'valor': 60  },
  {'class': 3, 'var': 2, 'valor': 520 },
  {'class': 1, 'var': 2, 'valor': 250 }
];

var arreglo2 = arreglo.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (a.class < b.class) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.class == b.class) {
    if (a.var < b.var) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.var == b.var) {
      return a.valor >= b.valor;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
});

console.log(arreglo2);
```

---

Y aquí puedes ver como también funciona si los valores fueran cadenas de texto:

```js
let arreglo = [
  {'class': '1', 'var': 'A', 'valor': 50  },
  {'class': '3', 'var': 'B', 'valor': 150 },
  {'class': '1', 'var': 'B', 'valor': 200 },
  {'class': '1', 'var': 'A', 'valor': 60  },
  {'class': '3', 'var': 'B', 'valor': 520 },
  {'class': '1', 'var': 'B', 'valor': 250 }
];

var arreglo2 = arreglo.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (a.class < b.class) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.class == b.class) {
    if (a.var < b.var) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.var == b.var) {
      return a.valor >= b.valor;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
});

console.log(arreglo2);
```

Comment: @AlvaroMontodo pero si se tratase de valores string no funcionaria, me refiero a los valores "class":"1", "var":"1", etc

Comment: @x-rw ¿Por qué no funcionaría? En esos casos se compararían los valores ASCII y la comparación y ordenación seguiría funcionando. He editado la respuesta con un ejemplo con cadenas además de números.

Answer (score 2):

Para ordenar manejo de arrays hay muchas funciones que se pueden usar sin tener que recurrir al `for` o al `while`en este caso se puede usar el método `Array.prototype.sort`.

La forma como se usa esta función es la siguiente:

1) declaro mi array:

```
 var myArray=[1,4,2,5,7,3];
```

2) lo ordeno:
     myArray.sort((a,b)=>{
          return a-b;
     });

el resultado seria:
     [1,2,3,4,5,7]
Lo que va dentro del sort es un callback que indica como debe ser ordenado el arreglo, para mas información mira este [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)

Entonces para ordenar tu array solo habria que adaptar el callback a tus necesidades:

```
 let arreglo=[{'class':1,'var':1, 'valor':50},
              {'class':3,'var':2, 'valor':150},
              {'class':1,'var':2, 'valor':200},
              {'class':1,'var':1, 'valor':60},
              {'class':3,'var':2, 'valor':520},
              {'class':1,'var':2, 'valor':250}];

 //primero ordenas por el parametro var, porque si ordenas por class primero
 //puede que al ordenar por var se desorganicen las class

 arreglo.sort((a,b)=>{return (a.var-b.var)});
 arreglo.sort((a,b)=>{return a.class-b.class});

 console.log(arreglo);
```

ya tu arreglo esta ordenado.